# How to edit and persist serializable Assets in the Editor Window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an asset saved in my project which represents a *serializable scriptable object*.
Code of the object is very simple:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScriptable : ScriptableObject {   
    public float gravity = .3f;
    public float plinkingDelay = .1f;
    public float storedExecutionDelay = .3f;    
}
```

There is no problem changing values for this object in the inspector, and the changes do persist and survive after exiting → entering *Unity*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I am trying to mimic the inspector behavior in an `Editor Window`. But any changes I do in the `Editor Window`, though reflected in the `Inspector`, do not persist.
Here is my two scripts which lay inside the `Editor` folder:

**the first one** (auxiliary) - this script replaces inspector fields (see image above) with button, which calls my custom `EditorWindow`.

```js
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TestScriptable))]
public class TestScriptableEditor : Editor {
  public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
    if (GUILayout.Button("Open TestScriptableEditor"))
      TestScriptableEditorWindow.Init();
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**the second** (with my problem) - script, where I'm trying to change my asset values:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class TestScriptableEditorWindow : EditorWindow {
    public static TestScriptableEditorWindow testScriptableEditorWindow;
    private TestScriptable testScriptable;

    [MenuItem("Window/TestTaskIceCat/TestScriptableEditor")]
    public static void Init() {
        // initialize window, show it, set the properties
        testScriptableEditorWindow = GetWindow<TestScriptableEditorWindow>(false, "TestScriptableEditorWindow", true);
        testScriptableEditorWindow.Show();
        testScriptableEditorWindow.Populate();
    }

    // initialization of my troubled asset              
    void Populate() {
        Object[] selection = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(TestScriptable), SelectionMode.Assets);        
        if (selection.Length > 0) {
            if (selection[0] == null)
                return;

            testScriptable = (TestScriptable)selection[0];
        }
    }

    public void OnGUI() {
        if (testScriptable == null) {
            /* certain actions if my asset is null */
            return;
        }

        // Here is my tries to change values
        testScriptable.gravity = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Gravity:", testScriptable.gravity);
        testScriptable.plinkingDelay = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Plinking Delay:", testScriptable.plinkingDelay);
        testScriptable.storedExecutionDelay = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Stored Execution Delay:", testScriptable.storedExecutionDelay);
        // End of the region of change values
    }    

    void OnSelectionChange() { Populate(); Repaint(); }
    void OnEnable() { Populate(); }
    void OnFocus() { Populate(); }

}
```

---

My questions is: what am I doing wrong? What could be the problem? How to fix it?  Am I loading the asset wrongly in the Editor Window? Or what?
Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, everything is simple and complicated, and simple again at the same time.

Despite the visual changes in the inspector - it doesn't mean that the data were actually changed. It looks like everything works fine, but......In my opinion it is shortcoming of the *Unity*

For correctly work you should use few things:

- [GUI.changed](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-changed.html) - returns true if any controls changed the value of the input data. We would be using it for changes detection.
- [Undo.RecordObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.RecordObject.html) - records any changes done on the object after the RecordObject function. The `Undo state` is recorded, allowing you to revert the change using the `Undo` system.
- [EditorUtility.SetDirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) (**!!!the most important thing!!!**) - shortly: marks target object as "dirty" and therefore requiring a save. For more information - click the link.

Now, all we need to do is to write some code at the bottom of the `OnGUI()` method;

```
if (GUI.changed) {
    // writing changes of the testScriptable into Undo
    Undo.RecordObject(testScriptable, "Test Scriptable Editor Modify"); 
    // mark the testScriptable object as "dirty" and save it
    EditorUtility.SetDirty(testScriptable); 
}
```

i.e. your code will be like this:

```js
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class TestScriptableEditorWindow : EditorWindow {
 public static TestScriptableEditorWindow testScriptableEditorWindow;
 private TestScriptable testScriptable;

 [MenuItem("Window/TestTaskIceCat/TestScriptableEditor")]
 public static void Init() {
  // initialize window, show it, set the properties
  testScriptableEditorWindow = GetWindow<TestScriptableEditorWindow>(false, "TestScriptableEditorWindow", true);
  testScriptableEditorWindow.Show();
  testScriptableEditorWindow.Populate();
 }

 // initialization of troubled asset 
 void Populate() {
  Object[] selection = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(TestScriptable), SelectionMode.Assets);        
  if (selection.Length > 0) {
   if (selection[0] == null)
    return;

   testScriptable = (TestScriptable)selection[0];
  }
 }

 public void OnGUI() {
  if (testScriptable == null) {
   /* certain actions if my asset is null */
   return;
  }

  testScriptable.gravity = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Gravity:", testScriptable.gravity);
  testScriptable.plinkingDelay = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Plinking Delay:", testScriptable.plinkingDelay);
  testScriptable.storedExecutionDelay = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Stored Execution Delay:", testScriptable.storedExecutionDelay);
  
  // Magic of the data saving
  if (GUI.changed) {
   // writing changes of the testScriptable into Undo
   Undo.RecordObject(testScriptable, "Test Scriptable Editor Modify");
   // mark the testScriptable object as "dirty" and save it
   EditorUtility.SetDirty(testScriptable); 
  }
 }    
  
 void OnSelectionChange() { Populate(); Repaint(); }
 void OnEnable() { Populate(); }
 void OnFocus() { Populate(); }
}
```

That's all. It was simple and easy.

---

Now the complicated-simple part of the story...

`SetDirty` - is certainly good. But this function is due to be deprecated in versions of Unity > 5.3. And also in some versions it will be removed. When? I dont't know. 
Instead of using `SetDirty` you could go another way:

All actions in the custom Editor or EditorWindow you should do between two calls:

```
serializedObject.Update()

// Here is some of your code

serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()
```

This code contains:

- [serializedObject.Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.Update.html) - Update serialized object's representation
- [serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties.html) - Apply property modifications.
- [serializedObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html) - gets the access to serialized object and gets his properties. SerializedObject is used in conjunction with:
- [SerializedProperty](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) - get the properties from the `serializedObject`. All data will be of SerializedProperty type, e.g.

  ```
  SerializedProperty myGravity = serializedObject.FindProperty("gravity");
  SerializedProperty myPlinkingDelay = serializedObject.FindProperty("plinkingDelay");
  ...
  etc.
  ```
- [SerializedObject.FindProperty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.FindProperty.html) - Find serialized property by name.
- [EditorGUILayout.PropertyField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html) - Make a field for `SerializedProperty`.

The last four is like the `SetDirty`: they will mark the modified object (or/and scene) as "dirty" and create `Undo states` for you.

So, knowing that, we could get something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class TestScriptableEditorWindow : EditorWindow {
    public static TestScriptableEditorWindow testScriptableEditorWindow;
    private TestScriptable testScriptable;
    // declaring our serializable object, that we are working on
    private SerializedObject serializedObj;

    [MenuItem("Window/TestTaskIceCat/TestScriptableEditor")]
    public static void Init() {
        testScriptableEditorWindow = GetWindow<TestScriptableEditorWindow>(false, "TestScriptableEditorWindow", true);
        testScriptableEditorWindow.Show();
        testScriptableEditorWindow.Populate();
    }

    // initialization of troubled asset
    void Populate() {
        Object[] selection = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(TestScriptable), SelectionMode.Assets);
        if (selection.Length > 0) {
            if (selection[0] == null)
                return;

            testScriptable = (TestScriptable)selection[0];
            // initialization of the serializedObj, that we are working on
            serializedObj = new SerializedObject(testScriptable);
        }
    }

    // our manipulation
    public void OnGUI() {
        if (testScriptable == null) {
            /* certain actions if my asset is null */
            return;
        }

        // Starting our manipulation
        // We're doing this before property rendering           
        serializedObj.Update();
        // Gets the property of our asset and скуфеу a field with its value
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObj.FindProperty("gravity"), new GUIContent("Gravity"), true);
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObj.FindProperty("plinkingDelay"), new GUIContent("Plinking Delay"), true);
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObj.FindProperty("storedExecutionDelay"), new GUIContent("Stored Execution Delay"), true);
        // Apply changes
        serializedObj.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    void OnSelectionChange() { Populate(); Repaint(); }
    void OnEnable() { Populate(); }
    void OnFocus() { Populate(); }
}
```

So, it is simple because you should use just

`Update` → actions → `ApplyModifiedProperties`.

But it is complicated because you should do a lot of work with bunch of property classes: `FindProperty`, `PropertyField` и `SerializedProperty`.

But when you understand how it works - it is becoming so easy...